# Check if a record exist in previous month ONLY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, sql-server-2012, data-analysis

I am working on a project to classify customers as 'existing' or 'new' in MS SQL server.

The rule for determining is to check the customer was with the company LAST month. Sample format below:

[image]

The expected result below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSyoW.png)

Customer A is an existing customer in Dec-22 and Jan-23 because it is in the table in the previous of these two months. However, you will find customer B appears twice as a NEW customer because there is no record of customer B in the month prior.

P.S. the month prior for customer B here is referring to Nov 2022 and Jan 2023, because there is no record of customer B in these two months. Customer B will need to be classified as NEW customer

May I know how to achieve the result?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thank you

I have done research on the internet and try to test myself. nothing worked

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.

Comment: You probably will want to look at LAG/LEAD. And then do a little date math on the previous row.

Comment: Customer B though is not new for the latest date as it exists already, and why is the first occurence of A not also labelled as New"?

Comment: @Stu, he probably clipped a few rows from the sample data

Comment: Hi @stu you are right, the 1st row of cust A should be New. However, for cust B, it will show as new two times because he is not in the datatable the month prior to those two months

Comment: @siggemannen you are right, its just a few rows as sample. however, cust B indeed shows this way in the datatable, thus cust B will classify as New cust in those two months because its not in the table the month prior to those two months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  *
,   CASE 
        WHEN EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, Date)) = EOMONTH(LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY date)) THEN 'Exist'
        ELSE 'New'
    END
  FROM  (
    SELECT  'A', '20221110'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'A', '20221231'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'A', '20230115'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'B', '20221231'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'B', '20230220'
) x (Customer, Date)
```

LAG(Date) allows to get previous date (partitioned by customer). Then just to be on a safe side, i convert the date to last day of month and compare to previous month's date.
If it's a match, it means customer already exists, otherwise he's marked as new, this also handles the case where there's no previous date at all

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH YOUR_TABLE_DATA(CUSTOMER,DATE) AS
(
  SELECT 'A','2022-11-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A','2022-12-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A','2023-01-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B','2022-12-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B','2023-02-28'
)
SELECT C.CUSTOMER,C.DATE,
CASE 
   WHEN SQ.DATE IS NULL THEN 'NEW'
   ELSE 'EXISTED'
END AS FLAG
FROM YOUR_TABLE_DATA AS C
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT X.DATE FROM YOUR_TABLE_DATA AS X
    WHERE X.CUSTOMER=C.CUSTOMER AND
     X.DATE=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,C.DATE))
)SQ
```

You can try something like this.